# Number of features of the model must match the input. Python error

Tags: python, python-3.x, random-forest, one-hot-encoding

This is a script that I'm using to make predictions in the biology field.

I'm studying the interactions between a peptide and a target: I used OneHotEncoding to encode each sequence of amino acids (they are the blocks of the peptide and they are represented by letters) and I have a label for each sequence that is called 'Ki' (identifies how good is the affinity to a target).

The error that I obtain is always the same:

> Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 133 and input n_features is 131.

This happen when a try to predict the 'Ki' of new sequences that are not present in the dataset. Any idea? Thank you in advance.

I thought that was a problem of the OHE, but seems to work. I don't know if the problem is in the input part.

**Load DataFrame**

```
df = pd.read_csv('sequences.csv', sep=';', header=None) 
df = df.iloc[1:]
```

**Encoding Part** (Only sequences)

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder 
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

encoder = LabelEncoder() cat = df.iloc[:, 1:-1] 
cat_encoded = cat.apply(encoder.fit_transform) 
encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto', sparse=False) cat_1hot =
encoder.fit_transform(cat_encoded.values)

X = cat_1hot #shape (69, 133) 
y = df.values[:, -1:].astype(float) #are number like 0.071, 1.935... shape(69, )
```

**Train Test Split, RF Regression, Evaluation... Load of new sequences**

```
test = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=';', header=None) 
test_ = test.iloc[1:, :]
```

**Encoding New Sequences**

```
encoder = LabelEncoder() 
cat = test_ cat_encoded = cat.apply(encoder.fit_transform)

encoder = OneHotEncoder(categories='auto', sparse=False) 
cat_1hot = encoder.fit_transform(cat_encoded.values) test_ohe = cat_1hot #shape (X, 131) X = number of sequences I choose
```

**Test**

```
results = np.round(rf_reg.predict(test_ohe), decimals= 3)
```

The last part doesn't work :(

This is how the df looks like.
[image: This is to explain how the df and test are]

Comment: Did you compare with other similar questions in [stackoverflow.com/search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Number+of+features+of+the+model+must+match+the+input.) and [datascience.stackexchange.com/search](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/search?q=Number+of+features+of+the+model+must+match+the+input.)? This Q&A [Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is `N` and input n_features is `X`.](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/33910/number-of-features-of-the-model-must-match-the-input-model-n-features-is-n-an) seems most helpful and related

Comment: Hi davedwards. Seems to be not my case, still doesn't work :( Using the reshape function I compare a single vector feature with more labels and that's wrong in my case. Don't know if I'm clear.

Comment: Hi Nicola, that error message might suggest after one hot encoding, do you have different number of train and test features?

Comment: Nope, same number of features. Anyway, in this case I solved the problem using a custom OHE. But in the future I would like to use the Sci-Kit package... Do you have any other idea? Thank you so much for your time.